# Battery recognized and 100% charged but not working

Tags: battery

I'm stumped.  Brand new to Linux, the battery became disabled while I had Vista running on my Lenovo Z61t.  It worked fine until Vista demanded I buy another license, I imagine the disabling of the battery is a tactic used by Windows to put additional pressure on the person why may be using a non-legitimate copy of their OS.  That was the last straw, I installed Ubuntu thinking it may take care of the problem.  Love the new OS but the battery issue persists.

Any benevolent suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The battery can not be "disabled".  If the laptop shuts down immediately when you unplug the power, then the battery is broken.  Usually even a very degraded battery should work for a few minutes though, but you did not really mention what the symptoms are.  "It does not work" is not a good error description.

Comment: I just can't imagine the battery died of natural causes.  It is relatively new and mysteriously decided to quit on me when Vista decided my install was suspect.  Just a few short weeks ago I could happily take my notebook around and enjoy at least an hour of battery life.  But, now I'm bound by the power supply, I unplug computer turns off immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The current battery is dead. Get a new battery.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a bad battery. If you search there are other threads about this.
Here is one -

["On battery" is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9401/on-battery-is-not-recognized)